# Implement two version of Window Close Event in one form ? C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two Windows form 1 , form 2

- Form 1 is the starting window which contains NextButton and a Datagrid with DatagridCheckboxcolumn.
- Form 2 is the second window which contains two buttons .

The scenario is when the user check one or more than row in the DataGrid and click on the NextButton. it will show the first window of form 2 that contains a window of a client information of the first row in the Datagrid of the form 1 and two buttons ( NextClient and finish ), there are two possibilities here ,

- The first is that he will check and click on Next it will show the next window of the next row ( client ) chosen by him ( by check ) in the datagrid of the form 1. ( work perfectly )
- The second he will check the user information's and click on finish , when He click on finish the window should be closed and it should not shown any other new window even if he checked many rows in the first datagrid of the form 1. ( Not working )

form 1 :

// Window closing of the form 2

```
 private void Window_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
// list grid count is the number of the list of the checked rows by the user

            compteur++;
            if (compteur < listgrid.Count)
            {
                
                Form2 form2 = new Form2();     
                Form2.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(Window_Closing);
                Form2.Show();

            }
            if (compteur == listgrid.Count)
            {

                nextBtn.IsEnabled = true;
                ClientGrid.IsEnabled = true;
            }
```

// form 2

```
    private void btn_Cancel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
      
    }
```

Is it possible to create two versions of Window Close Event in one form?

Comment: You have two buttons. Two click events. And you need two different pieces of code. They might both close their window but it's probably not the window close event you should be looking at.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood it right then what you want is to call two `Close` events when form is closed. And if so then it's pretty easy to implement.

```
public partial class ShellView : Window
{
    public ShellView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Closed += OnClosed;
        this.Closed += OnClosed2;
    }

    private void OnClosed2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can do so for any routed events for any element or control.

Comment: Thanks , I have found a solution but I have upvote your solution because it can be accepted as a soltuion

Comment: So this is not what you wanted exactly ?

Comment: No , that what I wanted but I have found other solution ( with different approach )

Comment: Thanks I will post my solution now

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by creating a variable called test in the form 2

```
// form 2
test= false;
   private void btn_Cancel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.test = true;
        this.Close();
      
    }
```

```
// Called the test variable in form 1
 private void Window_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (form2.test == true)
            {
                form2.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(Window_Closing);
                nextBtn.IsEnabled = true;
                ClientGrid.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else { 

            compteur++;

            if  (compteur < listgrid.Count)
            {
                    form2 = new Form2();
                    form2.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(Window_Closing);
                    form2.Show();

            }
```